# python set contains vs. list contains

Tags: python, list, set, contains, equality

i'm using python 2.7

consider the following snippet of code (the example is contrived):

```
import datetime

class ScheduleData:
    def __init__(self, date):
        self.date = date

    def __eq__(self, other):
        try:
            return self.date == other.date
        except AttributeError as e:
            return self.date == other

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.date)



schedule_set = set()
schedule_set.add(ScheduleData(datetime.date(2010, 8, 7)))
schedule_set.add(ScheduleData(datetime.date(2010, 8, 8)))
schedule_set.add(ScheduleData(datetime.date(2010, 8, 9)))

print (datetime.date(2010, 8, 8) in schedule_set)

schedule_list = list(schedule_set)

print (datetime.date(2010, 8, 8) in schedule_list)
```

the output from this is unexpected (to me, at least):

```
[08:02 PM toolscripts]$ python test.py
True
False
```

in the first case, the given date is found in the `schedule_set` as i have overridden the `__hash__` and `__eq__` functions.

from my understanding the `in` operator will check against hash and equality for sets, but for lists it will simply iterate over the items in the list and check equality.

so what is happening here? why does my second test for `in` on the list `schedule_list` fail?

do i have to override some other function for lists?

Comment: Works for me.. Python 3.3 I wonder why. Confirmed, it doesn't work on Python 2.7

Comment: try adding `__neq__` as well.

Comment: @tcaswell, thanks i did already try that and should've mentioned it, but it din't work - those `__ne__`, `__neq__` and `__eq__` functions don't seem to get called in the second case.

Comment: Compare `datetime.date(2010, 8, 8) == schedule_list[1]` to `schedule_list[1] == datetime.date(2010, 8,8)`.  Do you get `False` and then `True`?

Comment: False. The problem is with the class, i believe.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue is the comparison is invoking an `__eq__` function opposite of what you're looking for.  The `__eq__` method defined works when you have a `ScheduleData() == datetime.date()` but the `in` operator is performing the comparison in the opposite order, `datetime.date() == ScheduleData()` which is not invoking your defined `__eq__`.  Only the class acting as the *left-hand side* will have its `__eq__` called.

The reason this problem occurs in python 2 and not 3 has to do with the definition of `datetime.date.__eq__` in the std library.  Take for example the following two classes:

```
class A(object):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        print ('A.__eq__')
        return False

class B(object):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        print ('B.__eq__')

items = [A()]
B() in items
```

Running this code prints `B.__eq__` under both Python 2 and Python 3.  The `B` object is used as the lhs, just as your `datetime.date` object is used in Python 2.  However, if I redefine `B.__eq__` to resemble the Python 3 defintion of `datetime.date.__eq__`:

```
class B(object):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        print ('First B.__eq__')
        if isinstance(self, other.__class__):
            print ('B.__eq__')
        return NotImplemented
```

Then:

```
First B.__eq__
A.__eq__
```

is printed under both Python 2 and 3.  The return of `NotImplemented` causes the check with the arguments reversed.

Using `timetuple`  in your class will fix this problem, as @TimPeters stated (interesting quirk I was unaware of), though it seems that it need not be a function

```
class ScheduleData:
    timetuple = None
```

is all you'd need in addition to what you have already.

Comment: I would add that the behavior in this case depends on the use of `datetime.date` as the comparison type.  The same class works fine if you pass in, for instance, an int or string as the "date" value.  So the problem is also because `datetime.date` doesn't have the same automatic-both-sides-comparison behavior as the builtin types.

Comment: @BrenBarn I suspected this as well I'm looking at the library code right now

Answer (score 6):

@RyanHaining is correct.  For a truly bizarre workaround, add this method to your class:

```
def timetuple(self):
    return None
```

Then your program will print `True` twice.  The reasons for this are involved, having to do with an unfortunate history of comparisons in Python 2 being far too loose.  The `timetuple()` workaround is mostly explained in this part of the docs:

> Note In order to stop comparison from falling back to the
>   default scheme of comparing object addresses, datetime
>   comparison normally raises TypeError if the other comparand
>   isn’t also a datetime object. However, NotImplemented is
>   returned instead if the other comparand has a timetuple()
>   attribute. This hook gives other kinds of date objects a
>   chance at implementing mixed-type comparison. If not,
>   when a datetime object is compared to an object of a
>   different type, TypeError is raised unless the comparison
>   is == or !=. The latter cases return False or True,
>   respectively.

`datetime` was one of the first types added to Python that tried to offer less surprising comparison behavior.  But, it couldn't become "really clean" until Python 3.

Comment: thanks tim, i accepted ryan's answer, but yours is equally as helpful.